# How can we get the root project path in android lint check code?

Tags: android-studio, android-lint

I have a multi projects structure. One is the lint project including lint logic code. I wanna get the root project dir. I test some ways.

```
println("mainProject.dir ${context.mainProject.dir}")
println("mainProject.dir ${context.project.dir}")
```

But the ways above are just printing the current subproject path, not the gralde root project.

How can I do it? Should I need to put hard code path in the lint project ?